# How to create a instance of an array?

Tags: php

I want to create a cart like system to add items to an array and the display it. I don't know how to create an instance of an array and then save it into an another array.

```php
$_SESSION['cart'] = array();
$_SESSION['cartitem'] = array($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5);
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_SESSION['cartitem']);
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

I want to put the `$_SESSION['cartitem']` into `$_SESSION['cart']` and save it for next time so it adds another array next time into `$_SESSION['cart']` and display all saved arrays.

Edit: I want to add a new `$_SESSION['cartitem']` array to `$_SESSION['cart']`
so the output of `$_SESSION['cart']`after fist time will be Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => Big [2] => Solo [3] => Red [4] => 53 )) and second time Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => Big [2] => Solo [3] => Red [4] =>  53 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 16 [1] => Small [2] => Solo [3] => Blue [4] => 634 ) ) e.t.c ... so it adds another array from input values.

Comment: And what is the result of your current code?  You _are_ calling `session_start()` before any of this, right?

Comment: @PatrickQ yes i do , Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 15 [1] => Big [2] => Solo [3] => Red [4] => 53 ) )

Comment: Okay, so this is doing exactly what you want it to do except for "adds another array next time", which is covered by AbraCadaver's answer.

Comment: What are input values?  And why define `$_SESSION['cartitem']`???

Answer (score 2):

You are emptying `cart` every time with `$_SESSION['cart'] = array();`.  Also, you can add `cartitem` easier.  Oh, and you need `session_start`.  Your small code sample doesn't make a lot of sense, but in general:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['cartitem'] = array($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5);
$_SESSION['cart'][] = $_SESSION['cartitem'];
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Comment: So the problem now is that it saves two same arrays `$_SESSION['cartitem']` and I want it to remember last saved array and I want it to save multiple arrays with diffrent `$var1....$var5` variables

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.  You'll need to add more description/examples to question.

Comment: I added Edit to main question so maybe now you will know what I want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

I created a file named var.php and added this code

```php
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
?>
```

```php
$_SESSION['cartitem'] = array($var1,$var2,$var3,$var4,$var5);
array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $_SESSION['cartitem']);
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create the cartitem array as an array value of the cart variable. 
So:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = Array();
$_SESSION['cart']['cartitem'] = Array($var1......$var5);
print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
```

Leave a comment if you need more information / tips.